# set android:textAppearance with DataBinding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I am trying to set `android:textAppearance` with use of `DataBinding` , but it is not allowing me to use `?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge` with ternary operator.

```
android:textAppearance="@{position==1 ? ?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge : ?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium}"
```

It is showing me compile time error `<expr> expected, got '?'`.

Does there any other way to use this with DataBinding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use android.R.attr package instead of the ?android:attr

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import type="android.R.attr"/>

    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello world"
            android:textAppearance='@{age==1 ? android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge : android.R.attr.textAppearanceMedium}'
            tools:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            />


    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but somehow i cannot use it, because with this method it is overriding `typeFace` also, so not able to use custom font also.

Comment: It doesn't work because `android:textAppearance` expects style's `resource Id` but here the `attribute reference` is being passed. 

`android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"` works because XML parser looks up all given `?attr:...` to the actual `resourceId` for you. But *it does not work* in case of DataBinding expressions

Answer (score 11):

You cannot use it directly, however here's trick I use in such cases. Create own styles using `textAppearanceLarge` and `textAppearanceMedium` as parents and then set these styles instead:

First create `Foo` style:

```
<style name="Foo" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large">
   ... [whatever you need to set or override ] ...
</style>
```

and do the same for for `FooMedium`. Then edit your layout file as shown below. Note you must import project's `R` class in `<data>` block first:

```
<data>
   <import type="<your-package-id>.R"
</data>
```

Finally apply the appearance as you formerly wanted:

```
android:textAppearance="@{ position==1 ? R.style.Foo : R.style.FooMedium }"
```

Comment: +1 Seems like a nice workaround. However I cannot make it work for the style attribute: <expr> expected, got '?'  Can you confirm that it does not work for style?

Comment: You mean you want to use conditions witing `<style>` or when setting view's style? Neither will work though :(

Comment: yeah, I would like to set view style conditionally. There is an issue for this feature that is already one year old and it did not make it into any release 

Answer (score 4):

Looks like DataBinding treats `android:textAppearance` in some special way (at least on Android Studio 3.2.1).

For example the following expression according to [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions) should be fine, but **it is not**.

[image]

The following expression is being accepted by the compiler but **it is doing nothing**:

```
android:textAppearance="@{R.style.MyStyleTest}"
```

---

I have tried several options and only vanilla way worked for me:

```
android:textAppearance="@style/MyStyleTest"
```

### As a Solution

I would suggest to use `@BindingAdapter` and perform all the logic there.

For example if you would like to work with references to attributes (which looks like: `?attr/...`) use the following approach:

*layout.xml*

```
<TextView 
    ...
    bind:textAppearanceAttr="@{position==1 ? android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge: android.R.attr.textAppearanceMedium}" 
/>
```

*sources.kt*

```
@BindingAdapter(value = ["textAppearanceAttr"])
fun textAppearanceAttr(textView: TextView, @AttrRes attrRef: Int?) {
    attrRef?.also {
        val attrs = textView.context.obtainStyledAttributes(intArrayOf(attrRef))
        val styleRes = attrs.getResourceId(0, -1)
        attrs.recycle()
        if (styleRes != -1) {
            TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(textView, styleRes)
        }
    }
}
```

or in case of style resource ids (`@style/...`):

*layout.xml*

```
bind:textAppearanceStyle="@{position==1 ? R.style.MyStyleTest1: R.style.MyStyleTest2}"
```

*sources.kt*

```
@BindingAdapter(value = ["textAppearanceStyle"])
fun textAppearanceStyle(textView: TextView, @StyleRes style: Int?) {
    style?.also { TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(textView, it) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use textStyle instead of textAppearance,

Try to use code give below:

```
android:textStyle="@{position==1  ? @style/TextAppearance.Material.Large      :@style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium}"
```

[For more reference use below image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aREt.png)

Comment: This doesn't work, showing me same error `<expr> expected, got '?'`

Comment: `android:textStyle` has completely different purpose, it takes only `bold|italic|normal` and does not refers to any style.